# Changing the _ENV of a lua_thread (using C API)

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge, lua-5.3

This is for a multiplayer game where NPC scripts will be loaded and cached as function chunks on a single lua_State, and then each time a player interacts with an NPC, a new lua_thread is created, a cached function is fetched from a global lua_table and pushed onto the thread's stack, and then the thread is resumed (the npc script yields several times before finishing).

I am trying to change the environment of the lua thread using the C API, so that the function that has been loaded/run will not be able to change global variables / have them changed by other functions running on a different thread.

I achieved desired results by changing the functions environment, by adding this code to the start of my script. However I would like to do this using the C API side, so that I don't have to paste this code into every single script.

```
local newgt = {}
setmetatable(newgt, {__index = _G })
local _ENV = newgt
```

Example code + desired / current output

npcA.lua

```
x = 10
print(x)
y = 60
```

npcB.lua

```
print(x)
y = 25
player:someYieldingFunction()
print(y)
```

I expect that npcA print

```
10
```

and that npcB print

```
nil
25
```

The output currently is (this is not what I want)

if npcA runs first npcB would print

```
10
25
```

if npcB runs first and then yields, then npcA runs, and then npcB resumes.
npcB would print

```
10
60
```

which is problematic

Comment: A thread doesn't have `_ENV` variable.  A compiled chunk (a Lua function value) does have it, could be set by [lua_setupvalue](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_setupvalue) with `n=1`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff would I be able to set a different environment for the same chunk running on different threads?

Comment: Yes.  You should create separate function (with `lua_load`) for each thread and then set the environment for this function using `lua_setupvalue`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff yes but no; the _ENV upvalue isn't always the first one or they may not even be one at all.

Comment: To be honest, you're trying to fix something that's not a problem. Globals are meant to be global; if you don't want that, use locals instead.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lapi.c.html#lua_load and http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.2

Comment: @Green Again, yes but no. This only aplies to main chunks, i. e. chunks loaded directly from source code. It doesn't apply to functions though. The only safe way is to use the environment argument of `load` and `loadfile`, everything else is a hack and will most likely break things at some point.

Comment: @newbane2 - *According to remark from DarkWiiPlayer, I rephrased my comment:* You should create a separate function for each thread by compiling the same Lua code with `lua_load`; and then set thread-specific environment for this function using `lua_setupvalue`.  Compiling from Lua code guarantees that functions will have only one upvalue.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I can't find any examples of lua_load being used directly, are you referring to lua_loadfile() instead? Wouldn't doing so defeat the purpose of caching the function?

Comment: They are different closures (because have different upvalues).  No way to cache.  You can use `lua_loadfile()` instead of `lua_load()`.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer Could you share an example for *the _ENV upvalue isn't always the first one or they may not even be one at all* or source on that?

Comment: @Green According to the spec, no, as it's not defined, so one implementation could make _ENV the *last* upvalue of every function and it would still be valid Lua. That being said, in PUC Lua, the upvalues are numbered in the order they appear, so if you access (read OR write) any upvalue before accessing a global, that upvalue will come before _ENV.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I think I understand your concerns now. However, Lua reference states that functions loaded with `lua_load` will have env in first upvalue. You mentioned that, but Lua reference also clearly states that first upvalue of function loaded with either `loadfile` or `load` will be set to value of `env` parameter or global environment. If your concern was that loaded function might expect environment in arbitrary upvalue then using `load` or `loadfile` is unsafe and it is as unsafe as `lua_load` with `lua_setupvalue`. Only truly safe way is to set `_ENV` and then define function.

Comment: `load` and `loadfile` are safe for text (aka source code), but if you load binary data, it depends on whether that was dumped from a *main* block (aka. originally loaded as text), in which case it is also safe, or from a function, in which case it isn't.